# ListView setSelection and changing currently selected row text-color

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using LISTVIEW.setSelection(INT) in order to select certain items in my listview. I also need to chage style in row that is selected, namely to change color of the TextView element inside it. I don't know how to approach this problem. I've tried setting OnItemSelectedListener but it never gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

try this, If you are using ListActivity

```
View v=getListView().getChildAt(getSelectedItemPosition());
((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewID)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a list_item_color.xml in res/color/ like follow:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FFFFDD"/>
    <item android:color="#979B9E"/>
</selector>
```

and then use it in your layout xml. e.g.:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_color" />
```

the TextView will change text color automatically when you setSelection

Comment: the thing is that I set selection on listview object which forces particular row to be selected

Comment: when useing ListView, you must set a ListAdapter to it. there always need a layout resid when you new a subclass of ListAdapter. you can use "@color/list_item_color" in the layout which you pass to the ListAdapter

Comment: I don't quite understand how it's done - could you show me the sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as textview selector. use this as your text view background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/semitransparent_white" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/transparent" />
    </item>
</selector>
```